# How to Updating a variable using Jetpack compose ~ Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose

/**
Since there will be more than one button that can open the dialog window. For example Social Media button that open a different style of window . Phone Number where you can see the phone number..etc. So I want to have only one function that have all details regarding the dialog than each button will update the variable and pass it into the dialog Function.
*/

```
@Composable
fun CardSell(modifier: Modifier = Modifier){

    val (showDialog, setShowDialog) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var setDialogTitle : String = "" //Update this variable

    val padding = 9.dp
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column(Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = {})) {
        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Card(elevation = 4.dp) {
                Column {
                    Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp)){
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                            contentDescription = "Contact Profile Picture",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(40.dp)
                                .clip(CircleShape)
                        )
                    }

                    Row(modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(8.dp),
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly){

                        IconButton(
                            onClick = {
                                setShowDialog(true)
                                scope.launch {
                                    setDialogTitle = "Phone Number: ${user.contact.phoneNumber}"
                                    delay(100)
                                }

                            },
                        ) { //Phone Icon
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Filled.Phone,
                                contentDescription = "Phone Number"
                            )
                        }

                        }
                    }
                    
                    DialogDemo(showDialog, setShowDialog, setDialogTitle)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You wish to modify the `setDialogTitle` variable from where? I assume you wish to pass it into the `DialogDemo`, but where to modify it from? Elaborate

Answer (score 1):

In compose you never wanna use local variable without `remember`, this is not gonna save it state after recomposition

You can declare it in three ways:

1. By having both setter and getter, as you did with `showDialog`

```
val (value, setValue) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
```

2. By having single `MutableState` `val`

```
// declare
val setDialogTitle = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

// read/write
setDialogTitle.value = "new value"
```

3. Using delegated property. I find it most clean one:

```
// declare
var setDialogTitle by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

// read/write
setDialogTitle = "new value"
```

Check out more in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables)